# Menu is not working with any version of (IE)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

Dears, the menu is not working with any version of IE how I can solve the issue? below is my code, CSS and JS for the menu.

This is the menu:

```
<ul class="topnav">
  <li class="icon">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

This is my JS:

```
<script>
  /* Toggle between adding and removing the "responsive" class to topnav when the user clicks on the icon */
  function myFunction() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("topnav")[0].classList.toggle("responsive");
  }
</script>
```

and this is my CSS:

```
ul.topnav {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}


ul.topnav li {float: right;}


ul.topnav li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 17px;
}

ul.topnav li a:hover {background-color: #000000;}

ul.topnav li.icon {display: none;}


@media screen and (max-width:680px) {
  ul.topnav li:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  ul.topnav li.icon {
      float: right;
      display: inline-block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:680px) {
  ul.topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  ul.topnav.responsive li.icon {
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li {
      float: none;
      display: inline;
  } 
  ul.topnav.responsive li a {
      display: block;
      text-align: center;
  }
}
```

The code was taken from w3schools: http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_topnav.asp

I text them but no respond from them.

so what is wrong with the code please.

Comment: what exactly is ' not working ' in IE ?

Comment: not working in internet explorer. only works in Safari, chrome and firefox.

Comment: probably because `classList` not supported. Check errors in console. http://caniuse.com/#feat=classlist

Comment: If you're using jQuery, why not use the jQuery selector instead of classList?

Comment: I don't know how to do it. if you can send me the code by answer it will be perfect. :D

Comment: any one please ? @ghost_dad

Comment: can you help me please? @charlietfl

Comment: you need to confirm if that is problem. What errors are thrown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** I just saw what you were doing and looked the other comments and realized my errors. `classList` isn't supported so instead you can use `className += " .."`.

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.className += " imgWin";  // Add imgWin class to the div
div.appendChild(img);
content.appendChild(div);
```

If you get all your list items under the div like this and then finally append the class into your div, that should hopefully do the trick.

Comment: please can you write me the code please? @MarchingGazelle

Comment: @AbdulkarimGiraud I changed and made an edit, hope that helps. It's sample code. Then use `javascript` to just toggle between the classes

Comment: @AbdulkarimGiraud I'm glad it is :)